# Starship surface heating on Mars landing

Tags: spacex, reentry, spacex-starship, heat, entry-descent-landing

Mars atmosphere is much thiner than Earth's

And then how much will Starship heat on a Mars landing comparing to a landing on Earth?

Comment: SpaceX with Red Dragon was contemplating a strange approach, dive deep into the atmosphere and fly a lifting body in the dense atmosphere to better decelerate.  They did not report heating numbers in the presentation I saw.  NASA Likes to go in direct. SpaceX was planning to take it sporty. (Uhoh - no citations needed in a comment!)

Answer (score 6):

**Starship Earth LEO & Mars Return:**

[My answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/56021/40257) to [Starship reentry velocity on return from Mars: What are the options](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/55533/40257) talks about the Starship Mars to Earth return entry case. It draws heavily on [my answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/55725/40257) to [What is the heat shield refurbishment procedure for a crew Dragon capsule?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/55054/40257) to inform the heating analysis. Here is the key plot for this case, assuming a *best case scenario* inertial entry speed of 11.4 km/s, with a LEO reference on the right:

[image: Starship Mars return]
(Personal work)

The bottom "heat shield strain" plots are [explained here](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/55054/what-is-the-heat-shield-refurbishment-procedure-for-a-crew-dragon-capsule/55725#:%7E:text=A%20heat%20shield%20material%27s,P.%20et%20al.%202016) and the performance limits are specific to PICA, which SpaceX [improved upon in PICA-X](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/11978/40257). Existing evidence (*of admittedly questionable current-ness*) points towards "Starbrick" TPS being something akin to PICA-X, see [here (it's apparently ablative)](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/55533/starship-reentry-velocity-on-return-from-mars-what-are-the-options/56021#:%7E:text=Crew%20Dragon%20uses,a%20brake%20pad) and [here ("*leverages ablative heat shield materials developed for Dragon vehicles*")](https://youtu.be/5seefpjMQJI).

**The best case direct interplanetary entry speeds require Starship to *dissipate 16x more heat* than a LEO entry!**

**Starship at Mars:**

[SpaceX gives a Martian entry speed of 7.5 km/s](https://www.spacex.com/vehicles/starship/), presumably inertial (emphasis added):

> **Starship will enter Mars’ atmosphere at 7.5 kilometers per second and
> decelerate aerodynamically.** The vehicle’s heat shield is designed to
> withstand multiple entries, but given that the vehicle is coming into
> Mars' atmosphere so hot, we still expect to see some ablation of the
> heat shield (similar to wear and tear on a brake pad).

Which it is important to note is higher than a typical Mars direct entry:

| Mission: | Entry Speed (km/s): | Source: |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [MPF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Pathfinder) | 7.26 (inertial) | Ref. 1 |
| [MER-A&B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Exploration_Rover) | 5.4, 5.5 (inertial, respectively) | Ref. 1 |
| [Phoenix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoenix_(spacecraft)) | 5.6 (inertial) | Ref. 1 |
| [MSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Science_Laboratory) | 5.8 (relative) | Ref. 2 |
| [InSight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/InSight) | 5.8 (inertial) | Ref. 1 |
| [M2020](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_2020) | 5.3 (relative) | Ref. 2 |

(Mars surface rotation speed is ~250 m/s *at the equator*, re: difference between inertial and relative)

Perhaps this is an (unintended) result of [wanting to get to Mars faster](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/57572/40257).

Another factor working against Starship is its large mass. Depending on Starship's fuel/payload mass its ballistic coefficient, $\beta$, can range from a minimum of a few hundred to a maximum of a few thousand $\frac{kg}{m^2}$. Higher $\beta$ values necessitate steeper entries (larger entry flight path angle) which lead to higher inertial loading and higher peak heating. For reference, US Mars entry vehicles have had ballistic coefficients of ~60 (MPF, Phoenix, Insight, Ref 1), ~90 (MER-A&B, Ref. 1), & ~120 $\frac{kg}{m^2}$ (MSL, M2020, Ref. 3).

This leads to problems [alluded to in this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/9613/40257) and I think this is what [@geoffc's comment](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/48873/starship-surface-heating-on-mars-landing#comment158069_48873) is referring too. I also think [this is the presentation (Ref. 4)](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/20140013203) Geoff is referring to that contains this slide about [Red Dragon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpaceX_Red_Dragon):

[image: Red Dragon flight concept]

The strategy is to point your lift vector down until the vehicle is "about to crash into the surface" (for lack of a better description) then pull lift up to allow more time to decelerate in the denser lower atmosphere. This is what is seen in [this (relatively old) Starship animation](https://youtu.be/5seefpjMQJI). I have crudely tried to replicate the trajectory shown in that animation to analyze the heating (*similar methods from [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/55054/what-is-the-heat-shield-refurbishment-procedure-for-a-crew-dragon-capsule/55725#55725) adapted to Mars*):

[image: Starship Mars entry]

**The "heat shield strain" plot (right) shows that the direct Martian entry is much closer (heating wise) to a LEO entry than a Mars return Earth entry/lunar return entry.**

Note though that these heating analyses are [about an order of magnitude accurate estimation](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/12746/40257), when applied correctly (i.e., blunt, sphere-cone entry vehicles, which Starship is *not*).

**References:**

1. Korzun, A. et al. "Aerodynamic Performance of the 2018 InSight Mars Lander," (2020) [NTRS ID: 20200002812](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/20200002812)
2. Edquist, K. et al. "Mars 2020 Reconstructed Aerothermal Environments and Design Margins" (2021) [NTRS ID: 20210024709](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/20210024709)
3. Noyes, C. "Robust Optimal Entry Guidance for Future Mars Landers DISSERTATION," (2021) ([archived link](https://web.archive.org/web/20220226173855/https://escholarship.org/content/qt7bv3q5ws/qt7bv3q5ws_noSplash_c86bb12206e0b1619b101bde21b1572f.pdf))
4. A. A. Gonzales et al., "Mars Sample Return Using Commercial Capabilities: Propulsive Entry, Descent and Landing," 2014 IEEE Aerospace Conference, 2014 [NTRS ID: 20140013203](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/20140013203)